# SQL Count number of occurrences for each distinct combination

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the count for each distinct combination of two columns. Here is the query to get the distinct combinations.

```
SELECT distinct Sales_Cat, Sub_cat
FROM rtx_Sales
```

It returns all combinations as seen below. I need to add a count field that also shows the number of occurrences for each of the combinations. Is SQL capable of this or should I write a python script to query for each combo?

[image]

Comment: I think follow an SQL course, and find out what `GROUP BY` can do .... see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: `select sales_cat, sub_cat, count('Dracula') as cnt from rtx_sales group by sales_cat, sub_cat`

Comment: been a few years since I have touched sql so yes I do need a refresher lol - thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNT()

```
SELECT sales_cat, sub_cat, COUNT(*)
FROM rtx_sales 
GROUP BY sales_cat, sub_cat
```